# How i can switch the language on payment status in orders page on shopify admin?

Tags: admin, shopify

I want to change the language to spanish on payment status and fulfillment status.
For example:

Authorized === Autorizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not posible yet because Shopify admin hasn't been yet internationalized. You could write some JavaScript injection (Tampermonkey) to accomplish this, though.